# How to send a POST request conditionally to login or sign up users

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I am trying to send a POST request to either SIGN UP or LOGIN a user depending on whether the `prop` (`isSignUp`) is `true` or `false` in my state.

What I want to happen:

I would like one API endpoint to be hit if `isSignUp` is true and the other to be hit if it is not.

Individually the endpoints work however when I connect everything up I am only able to sign people in and not log them in once they are signed up.

State:

```
state = {
    controls: {
      email: {
        elementType: "input",
        elementConfig: {
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Email Address"
        },
        value: "",
        validation: {
          required: true, // must not be empty
          isEmail: true
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false
      },
    isSignUp: true
 }
};
```

handlers:

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    this.props.onAuth(
      this.state.controls.email.value,
      this.state.controls.password.value,
      this.state.controls.isSignUp
    );
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  switchAuthModeHandler = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      console.log(prevState);
      return {
        isSignUp: !prevState.isSignUp
      };
    });
  };
```

logic to switch button text and trigger authModeHandler

```
 return (
      <div className={classes.Auth}>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          {form}
          <Button btnType="Success">SUBMIT</Button>
        </form>
        <Button clicked={this.switchAuthModeHandler} btnType="Danger">
          SWITCH TO {this.state.isSignUp ? "SIGN IN" : "SIGN UP"}
          {console.log(this.state.isSignUp)}
        </Button>
      </div>
    );

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onAuth: (email, password, isSignUp) =>
      dispatch(actions.auth(email, password, isSignUp))
  };
};
```

Actions which trigger the POST requests to login or sign up a user

```
export const auth = (email, password, isSignUp) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(authStart());
    const authData = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      returnSecureToken: true
    };

    {
      isSignUp
        ? axios
            .post(
              "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=AIzaSyAGT2vM3uzywo3zQUAxNnkpPB6Yr3Ohets",
              authData
            )
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response);
              dispatch(
                authSuccess(response.data.idToken, response.data.userId)
              );
            })
        : axios
            .post(
              "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=AIzaSyAGT2vM3uzywo3zQUAxNnkpPB6Yr3Ohets",
              authData
            )
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response);
              dispatch(
                authSuccess(response.data.idToken, response.data.userId)
              );
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              dispatch(authFail(err));
            });
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in State you put `isSignup` **NOT** under controls so you should access it via `this.state.isSginUp`

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    this.props.onAuth(
      this.state.controls.email.value,
      this.state.controls.password.value,
      this.state.isSignUp
    );
    event.preventDefault();
  };
```

P.S I suggest to use Redux dev tools. it saves lives. happy coding!